# Obtener los registros de las últimas 3 horas de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy buscando la manera de obtener los registro guardados solo en la ultimas 3 horas de una tabla.
En un campo que utiliza este formato de hora "2021-03-31 00:00:51"

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Fecha,"%Y-%m-%d") = CURDATE();
```

Estoy usando esta query pero me devuelve los datos de todo el dia, y yo necesito solo de las ultimas 3 horas

Comment: Agrega que llevas al momento

Comment: SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Fecha`,"%Y-%m-%d") = CURDATE();        estoy usando esta query pero me devuelve los datos de todo el dia, y yo necesito solo de las ultimas 3 horas.

Comment: Y que motor de base de datos utilizas? agrégalo en las etiquetas de tu pregunta

Comment: Pero probaste algo para devolver horas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El uso de la función [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) en este caso tomará tu columna de fechas y solo entregará los valores con un formato como este:

```
año-mes-dia
```

Aunado a lo anterior, la función: [`curdate()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) retorna solo el año-mes-dia

Por lo que la igualdad que estás buscando en tu consulta dejará de lado el factor tiempo

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR) AND NOW();
```

Lo que hicimos fue:

- Obtener todos los registros que existan dentro de un rango que:

  - A la fecha actual le quitamos 3 horas
  - Obtenemos al final la fecha y hora actual

Aqui te dejo [el enlace de las funciones de fecha y tiempo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) para que revises sobre `NOW()` y `DATE_SUB`

Comment: Gracias. esto soluciono mi problema.